# AWS lambda with python and langchain in docker: No module named 'langchain' (Runtime.ImportModuleError)

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda, langchain

I cannot make my python script run in `AWS lambda` using `langchain` as a dependency in a docker-container. I got the docker-container created and the lambda-function deployed correctly. But as soon as I try to execute it, I get the message:

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'handler': No module named 'langchain'"
```

Does anyone know why?

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY handler.py ./

# for chromaDB
RUN yum install gcc-c++ -y

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# CPU only version of pytorch (smaller)
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu

CMD [ "handler.handler" ]
```

This is my `requirements.txt`:

```
transformers
langchain
chromadb
pypdf
xformers
sentence_transformers
InstructorEmbedding
boto3
```

This is my `handler.py`:

```
import sys
print("SYS-Path:")
print(sys.path)

import json
import torch

from langchain.document_loaders import ( 
    AmazonTextractPDFLoader,
    DirectoryLoader,
    TextLoader
)
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma

# langchain/chromaDB logic here ...

def handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    print(context)
    body = json.loads(event.get('body'))

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": True

        },
        "body": {
            "result": "ok"
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the output of `print(sys.path)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had to set `PYTHONPATH` in my `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/lib:${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/lib/python:${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/lib/python3.9"
```